# Grouping is not working on Tockenized Fields-Apache Solr

Tags: solr

```
<fieldType name="SearchTokenizer" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
 <analyzer type="index">
 <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15"/>
</analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
```

I have defined the field Type as above and it is used against the field say 'price'. When I searched for price:20 and even the search is returning multiple records such as 200,200, 201,202,202, it is not grouped properly for the query group=true&group.field=price.
How we can bring grouping on Tockenized Fields? Please help.

Comment: What do you expect the grouped result to be? The NGram filter will create a large amount of field values, and grouping is done pr. token. Are you sure you really want ngrams?

Comment: @MatsLindh:  I have to perform search for 'almost similar values/similar values/atleast any of letter contained' against the entered text. ie., for example.. in document if the value is 2345abcgh and it should be searched for 2 or 3 or cgh or 45abc (any of tockens of the value). Thats why i have chosen Ngram filter. I need grouping as well along with this.

Comment: So what do you actually want to group against? The actual value of the field, or the ngram-ized tokens?

Comment: For example ,fields ItemType , ItemName, price - if i am using ngram-ized type on itemType  then also results should be grouped based on itemType as follows: {'mobile' :[{'samsung','24000'},{'nokia','22000'}]},{"television":[{"onida","50000"},{"panasonic","75000"}]}

Comment: Add a field that's just the value you want to group on, use `copyField` to populate both fields, but don't ngram that field. Use that field only for grouping.

Comment: @MatsLindh: Thanks a lot, this really worked for grouping. But right now i am using group=true&group.field=someField  . For each group it is returning total record count and a top most record. How we can get all records under each group. I have used grouplimit, but here i cant predict number of records for each group. Please help how i can resolve this.